# How to detect whether \PassOptionsToPackage was already called?

Tags: optional-arguments, package-options, class-options, options

If I call:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber,style=numeric,backref=false}{biblatex}

% And later someone else call again
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=abnt,backend=biber}{biblatex}
```

What will happen?

Can I detect whether someone else had already called `\PassOptionsToPackage` and do not override their definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\PassOptionsToPackage` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 7784:
\def\PassOptionsToPackage{\@pass@ptions\@pkgextension}
```

and we can look at `\@pass@ptions`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 7778:
\def\@pass@ptions#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname opt@#3.#1\endcsname{%
    \@ifundefined{opt@#3.#1}\@empty
      {\csname opt@#3.#1\endcsname,}%
    \zap@space#2 \@empty}}
```

Suppose we call `\PassOptionsToPackage{baz}{foo}`. If `\opt@foo.sty` (can only be formed with `\csname`) is undefined, it is defined to expand to `baz`. If it is already defined, say to `gnu,gnat`, then it will be redefined to expand to `gnu,gnat,baz`.

The latter case can happen either if `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{foo}` has already been called or the package has already been loaded. In the second case `\PassOptionsToPackage{baz}{foo}` does nothing.

As you see, new sets of options are chained to the already existing ones. It's then a job of the package, when loaded, to make its way amongst them.

This should also answer your question about detection: you can use

```
\ifcsname opt@foo.sty\endcsname
  <options have already been passed or the package has already been loaded>
\else
  <no options have been passed yet>
\fi
```